# How to include leaflet library locally in project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, leaflet

I am looking to add leaflets entire library to my project files instead of using the http link. I have followed the following instructions from leaflet : [image]
My index.html is as follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
<meta
  name="description"
  content="Search UI"
/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
<!--
  manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
  user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
-->
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/leaflet/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--
  Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
  It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
  Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

  Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
  work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
  Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
-->
<title>React App</title>
```

You'll notice I haven't attempted to change the other leaflet components just yet. I use the %public_url% so that when the project is cloned, the path adjusts accordingly upon build. So in order to maintain this, I have put the leaflet library in the public folder. This causes an issue when I try to compile the JS file that utilizes the leaflet map.

This is how I used to import/use leaflet :

```
import * as L from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet-draw'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-easybutton'
```

Now when I attempt to use the local libary instead, I run into the issue of

```
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../public/leaflet/leaflet-src which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

After some investigation I saw there are ways to get around this, but I feel like there is a better way that I am simply missing.

My goal is to have `import * as L from 'leaflet'` use the leaflet library in the project files, not the leaflet that is still in my node modules. I will then apply the same logic to the css, and follow up with the rest of the leaflet components I am using.

The class file directory structure is project_name/src/Components/Map/MapSearch.js

Any insight towards a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What build engine do you use? Do you use a framework?

Comment: @ghybs The React framework and we use docker as the build engine